# ElasticSearch converting the text to lowercase

Tags: elasticsearch

I have not specified any analyzer and I have a field which has a hex. String where all the letters present are being converted to lower case.

How do I stop it (what's analyzer/token filter should be used)?

Answer (score 1):

If an analyzer is not specified then the default standard analyzer and the keyword analyzer are applied, they do the following:

> **Standard Analyzer**
>
> The standard analyzer divides text into terms on
> word boundaries, as defined by the Unicode Text Segmentation
> algorithm. It removes most punctuation, lowercases terms, and supports
> removing stop words.
>
> **Keyword Analyzer**
>
> The keyword analyzer is a “noop” analyzer that
> accepts whatever text it is given and outputs the exact same text as a
> single term.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html

To access the no-op (no operation) keyword analyzer where case is preserved add  `.keyword` to the end of the field name like so:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term" : { 
      "hex_value.keyword" : "#00FF00" 
    } 
  }
}
```

This will perform the case sensitive search sought after.